# Bootstrap 3 Space between navbar-brand and navbar ending

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an issue with Bootstrap 3. I don't know why, but in mobile screen there is space between navbar-brand and navigation bar ending. I guess, it is because of navigation bar glyphicon doesn't fit my navigation bar. How can I solve this issue? I just need to remove that empty space...

Desktop-size version:

[image: desktop-size]

Mobile-size version:

[image: mobile-size]

HTML:

```
    <header class="top" role="header">
        <div class="container">

            <a href="../aplikacija/app.html" class="navbar-brand pull-left">
                    Brand
            </a>

            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
            </button>

            <nav class="navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation">
                <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
div.container {
    background-color: #474747;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

a.navbar-brand {
    text-shadow: none;
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #474747;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

ul.navbar-nav li a{
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #ccc;
}

ul.navbar-nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #373737;
    color: #ccc
}

button.navbar-toggle {
    color: #ffffff;
}

span.glyphicon {
    color: #009B9B;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the space between the toggle icon and the right side of your navigation? Can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I mean space between grey rectangle and big green rectangle.

Comment: Ah okay, now I understand, pretty hard to see ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove this space by removing the `margin-bottom` from the `.navbar-toggle`:

```
button.navbar-toggle {
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
```

`!important` is optional, i can't tell you right now if you need this, just test it.